# Java/Android - Why do I get different runtime on running this code?

Tags: java, android, runtime

I wrote this code and I was surprised to see different runtime for everytime I run this code. Also I tried this on Android and I have the same problem
And there are no other methods or class.

```
public class Sample1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long i = System.nanoTime();
        for (int k = 1; k <= 1000000; k++) {
            //
        }
        System.out.print(System.nanoTime() - i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by different runtime?

Comment: What makes you think that you should always get the same execution time ?

Answer (score 1):

Some machines will run the code faster than others. And it may run at different speeds on any given machine due to it sharing the CPU with other processes.

Also, some Java compilers will optimise out the `for` loop entirely as it's a no-op.